# BSONRmgExp is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am working through a Node.js tutorial and we just started working with Mongoose. Everything has been going great until today. I turned on my computer and opened WebStorm. I went to run what we had last worked on and I get the following stack trace:

```
/usr/bin/node /home/doug/Documents/node-course/task-manager/src/db/mongoose.js
/home/doug/Documents/node-course/task-manager/node_modules/bson/index.js:41
BSON.BSONRegExp = BSONRmgExp;
                  ^

ReferenceError: BSONRmgExp is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/doug/Documents/node-course/task-manager/node_modules/bson/index.js:41:19)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1236:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1257:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1125:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:75:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/doug/Documents/node-course/task-manager/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/index.js:3:12)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1236:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1257:10)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Here is the code I have:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
//
// // mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/task-manager-api', {
// //     useNewUrlParser: true,
// //     useCreateIndex: true
// // });
//
// // const User = mongoose.model('User', {
// //     name: {
// //         type: String,
// //     },
// //     age: {
// //         type: Number
// //     }
// // });
//
//
// // const Task = mongoose.model('Task', {
// //     description: {
// //         type: String
// //     },
// //     completed: {
// //         type: Boolean
// //     }
// // });
//
// //
// // const newTask = new Task({
// //     description: 'This is a new task added by mongoose.',
// //     completed: false
// // });
// //
// // newTask.save().then((newTask) => {
// //     console.log(newTask);
// // }).catch((error) => {
// //     console.log('Error!', error);
// // });
//
// // const me = new User({
// //     name: 'Doug',
// //     age: 30
// // });
// //
// // me.save().then((me) => {
// //     console.log(me);
// // }).catch((error) => {
// //     console.log('Error!', error);
// // });
```

With everything commented out except for my require, I still get the error. If I comment out require, it runs.

Searching "ReferenceError: BSONRmgExp is not defined" is bringing up nothing that I can find.

Does anyone have a suggestion as to how I can fix this or what is causing it?

EDIT: Here is the file it is referencing which is located in the node_modules folder.

index.js

```
var BSON = require('./lib/bson/bson'),
  Binary = require('./lib/bson/binary'),
  Code = require('./lib/bson/code'),
  DBRef = require('./lib/bson/db_ref'),
  Decimal128 = require('./lib/bson/decimal128'),
  Double = require('./lib/bson/double'),
  Int32 = require('./lib/bson/int_32'),
  Long = require('./lib/bson/long'),
  Map = require('./lib/bson/map'),
  MaxKey = require('./lib/bson/max_key'),
  MinKey = require('./lib/bson/min_key'),
  ObjectId = require('./lib/bson/objectid'),
  BSONRegExp = require('./lib/bson/regexp'),
  Symbol = require('./lib/bson/symbol'),
  Timestamp = require('./lib/bson/timestamp');

// BSON MAX VALUES
BSON.BSON_INT32_MAX = 0x7fffffff;
BSON.BSON_INT32_MIN = -0x80000000;

BSON.BSON_INT64_MAX = Math.pow(2, 63) - 1;
BSON.BSON_INT64_MIN = -Math.pow(2, 63);

// JS MAX PRECISE VALUES
BSON.JS_INT_MAX = 0x20000000000000; // Any integer up to 2^53 can be precisely represented by a double.
BSON.JS_INT_MIN = -0x20000000000000; // Any integer down to -2^53 can be precisely represented by a double.

// Add BSON types to function creation
BSON.Binary = Binary;
BSON.Code = Code;
BSON.DBRef = DBRef;
BSON.Decimal128 = Decimal128;
BSON.Double = Double;
BSON.Int32 = Int32;
BSON.Long = Long;
BSON.Map = Map;
BSON.MaxKey = MaxKey;
BSON.MinKey = MinKey;
BSON.ObjectId = ObjectId;
BSON.ObjectID = ObjectId;
// BSON.BSONRegExp = BSONRmgExp;
BSON.Symbol = Symbol;
BSON.Timestamp = Timestamp;

// Return the BSON
module.exports = BSON;
```

If I comment out the line "BSON.BSONRegExp = BSONRmgExp;", then everything runs. I tried searching Google for the line in quotations and it has no results.

EDIT 2: I'm guessing it has something to do with MongoDB but the [documentation isn't very helpful](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/functions/json-and-bson/#bson-bsonregexp) for this specific issue.

Answer (score 0):

Tried `BSON.BSONRegExp = BSONRegExp;` instead of `BSON.BSONRegExp = BSONRmgExp;` ?

Comment: Is this an answer? Reads like a clairfication question, which should be a comment. If you mean this to be an answer please add explanation to make it helpful.